# Android - adb setprop persist.sys.locale not working on emulator

Tags: android, adb

When I change the system locale, it is not working, the emulator is restarted but it is still displayed in the original locale.

Any thoughts?

```
$ adb root
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
restarting adbd as root
$ adb shell "setprop persist.sys.locale es-AR; stop; sleep 2; start"
$ adb shell getprop persist.sys.locale 
en-US
```

Comment: Are you sure the property service hat enough time to save the changed value? Anyway as we are talking about the emulator why not setting the property via command-line of the emulator (`-prop`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have no idea on what caused this. But this solved:

In Android Studio - Tools -> AVD Manager -> select the emulator and then "Wipe data".

Answer (score 0):

Please check Android version on your emulator.

Android Marshmallow needs to set like "setprop persist.sys.locale es-AR".
On the other hands, Android Kitkat needs to set both "setprop persist.sys.language es" and "setprop persist.sys.country AR".
I'm not sure when this setting was changed exactly. (between K ~ M somewhere)